# No parameterless constructor defined for the object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore

Just upgraded to from SC 8.0 to 8.1 Update3 and started see `No parameterless constructor defined for the object` error.
Any ideas what could be different between 8.0 and 8.1 rendering?
Solution includes Glass Mapper as well. I did not add any Areas since the 8.0 build was single site setup.

Full error:

```
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +138
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +105
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +73
[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'XOM.HR.Web.Controllers.Page.PageChromeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +240
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +103
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +96
[ControllerCreationException: Could not create controller: 'PageChrome'. 
The context item is: '/sitecore/content/Home'. 
The current route url is: '{*pathInfo}'. This is the default Sitecore route which is set up in the 'InitializeRoutes' processor of the 'initialize' pipeline. ]
 Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +202
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +267
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +95
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +27
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +3614
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) +131
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) +595
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName) +52
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared_Layouts_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Website\Views\Shared\Layouts\Index.cshtml:5
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +137
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343
[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '~/Views/Shared/Layouts/Index.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +30
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +75
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
```

Comment: Is your project supposed to be using a DI container?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be untouched though from sc8.0 upgrade.

Comment: You need to add PageChrome in to your di config :).  Have a look at https://cardinalcore.co.uk/2015/02/03/resolving-sitecore-controllers-from-your-ioc-container/

Comment: Or use a chained resolver to allow Sitecore to resolve it's own dependencies: http://www.seanholmesby.com/safe-dependency-injection-for-mvc-and-webapi-within-sitecore/